# how we can add a new task in celery without stop celery instance in django celery?

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery, celerybeat, djcelery

```
@shared_task
def forgot_email(subject,user_cipher,key_cipher,to):
   print "comes here in the mail"
   try:
      email_content = {'user_cipher':user_cipher,'key_cipher':  key_cipher}
      message = render_to_string('forgot_password.txt',email_content)
      send_mail(subject, message, settings.EMAIL,to, fail_silently=False) 
      except Exception,e:
      print "Exception",e
    except:
       print 'exp'

@shared_task
def multiplesendmail(subject,body,first_name,to):
    print "comes here in the mail"
    try:
        print 'subject',subject,'body',body,'first_name',first_name,'to',to
        # email_content = {'first_name':first_name,'user_cipher':user_cipher,'key_cipher':key_cipher}
        # message = render_to_string('email_verification.txt', email_content)
        send_mail(subject,body,settings.EMAIL,to,fail_silently=False) 
    except Exception,e:
        print "Exception",e
```

Note- I want to add a new task without stopping celery.  I have to use this first stop celery and then

```
celery -A HealthBrio worker -l info
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a link for what you want. You can set up crontab using admin interface of django. 
There are two ways to start a task:

By scheduler, that will call the task every time period (10 seconds for example) or every particular time (like crontab do).
From code, in needed place and under needed conditions.
Launch task by scheduler
Go to admin page at address http://{host}/admin/djcelery/periodictask/ and press "Add periodic task".

Fill fields as it is shown in screenshot below and press save.
[image]

Launch periodic task every 10 seconds

To indicate launch time instead of period, do the same, as in previous case, but fill Crontab (Interval must be blanked):
[image]

More detail at http://www.lexev.org/en/2014/django-celery-setup/